# Upgraded 10.9.1 to 10.9.2 now SD cards not recognized

Tags: sd-card

On early 2011 MacBook Pro 15inch -- I use the SD card slot a lot. Suddenly after the upgrade to 10.9.2 (for security reasons), now inserting an SD card gets no reaction, instead of showing an icon on the desktop for the new mounted volume.

Comment: Have you already checked the Finder's Preference settings (Cmd-comma)?

Comment: Yes, Finder Preferences is set to show everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try another brand of sd card, I had this problem with sandisk cards but al others would work perfectly.
You can also try wiggling it around a bit after a while it would read my cards if I did that.
Just don't break the card ;)

Comment: I have currently handy only Transcend and SanDisk cards. I've tried both and the result is the same: not recognized. And this started only when I upgraded to 10.9.2 recently.

Comment: and when you wiggle it around a bit?

Comment: Eureka. That did it. Must have gotten dirt on the contacts -- now they're clean and the problem is gone. Weird of course that this happened simultaneously with the MacOS upgrade, but clearly that was a coincidence. Thanks, Dennis!!

Answer (score -1):

same problem' was working, now not. 2 brands of card tried. wiggled without success. am I going to have to resort to the abandoned PC in the corner? this is deffo a 10.9.2 problem.